# How do I close a InterSystems.Data.CacheClient.dll database connection?

Tags: c#, .net, intersystems-cache

My connection to Caché doesn't close until the entire app \ IIS finishes.

For example, make a new project referencing InterSystems.Data.CacheClient.dll
and try the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var connection = new CacheConnection("SERVER=10.10.10.41;PORT=1972;DATABASE=dsa-som-ting;PROTOCOL=TCP;UID=user;PWD=password;");

    connection.Open();      
    Console.ReadKey();  //open

    connection.Close();     
    Console.ReadKey(); //still open!

    connection.Dispose();       
    Console.ReadKey(); //still open!
}
```

The connection remains open the whole time, as I can see in the Caché portal:
[image]

How do I close the connection??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET uses connection pooling to keep up to 100 connections open by default until an application ends.

So even though you call connection.Close(), and it appears closed in your app, .NET keeps a copy of it open for use later when you call connection.Open() to save time.

To alter the size of the pool use a connection string like:

```
new CacheConnection("SERVER=10.10.10.41;PORT=1972;DATABASE=dsa-clb-def;PROTOCOL=TCP;UID=_System;PWD=sys;Max Pool Size=50;");
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create a custom class that implements IDisposable interface. This helps with GC and allows you to more easily close your connection.

```
class CustomCacheConnection : IDisposable
{
    private static string connString;

    private static CacheConnection conn;
    private static CacheCommand cmd;

    public CustomCacheConnection(string sql)
    {
        conn = new CacheConnection();
        connString = GetConnectionString();
        cmd = new CacheCommand(sql, conn);
    }

    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposed = false; // To detect redundant calls

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                cmd.Dispose();

                //make sure the connection state is open so we can close it
                if (conn != null && conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }

            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    // This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
        Dispose(true);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Then in your Main()

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Sample.Person";

using (CustomCacheConnection connection = new CustomCacheConnection(sql))
{
     //do stuff
}
```